# pandas series subset index 2:-2 doens't work

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe.

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'t': np.array(['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']),
                   'o': np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])})
```

I can't understand why this works:

```
print(dd.loc[2:4, 'o'].values)

[3, 4, 5]
```

and this doesn't :

```
print(dd.loc[2:-2, 'o'].values)

[]
```

while this does:

```
print(dd[['o']][2:-2].values)

[[3]
 [4]
 [5]]
```

Comment: `loc` is label selection; what you are doing is indexing by position -> try `iloc` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wnat use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for label selection is possible it, but need indexing `dd.index`:

```
print(dd.loc[dd.index[2:-2], 'o'].values)
[3 4 5]
```

If use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by positions is necessary position of `o` column by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
print(dd.iloc[2:-2, dd.columns.get_loc('o')].values)
[3 4 5]
```

---

Last selecting is more complicated, it seems one column DataFrame in seelcting working like selecting by Series:

```
print(dd[['o']][2:-2])
#working like
#print(dd[['o']].iloc[2:-2])
   o
2  3
3  4
4  5

print(dd['o'][2:-2])
#working like
#print(dd['o'].iloc[2:-2])
2    3
3    4
4    5
Name: o, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Ok, but then , why `dd.loc[2:4, 'o'].values` works

Comment: @George - I think because is possible select between labels,better it is possible seen in `dd.index = list('ABCDEFG')
print(dd.loc['C':'E', 'o'].values)`

Answer (score 4):

### Why dd.loc[2:4, 'o'].values works

`.loc[]` uses [label slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label), where label is treated as non-monotonic and thus [require exact matches](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#non-monotonic-indexes-require-exact-matches). [Endpoints are inclusive](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing).

Therefore, in `.loc[]`, `2:4` is interpreted as `2:4:1 (inclusive)`. So rows with `index = 2, 3, and 4` are selected.

### How dd.loc[2:-2, 'o'].values works

For the same reasoning above, `2:-2` in `.loc[]` won't translate into a length-aware `2:len(dd)-2:1` as expected. This is because `2` and `-2` are regarded as nominal labels, hence the slicing expression WON'T be length-aware. It will be interpreted as `2:-2:1 (inclusive)` instead of `2:len(dd)-2:1 (inclusive)` .

However, since the first element 2 is already crossing the boundary of ending point (2 > -2), no element will be selected. This results in an empty dataframe.

### dd[2:-2]

This is called [slicing ranges](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-ranges).

Taken from the docs:

- The most robust and consistent way of slicing ranges along arbitrary axes is described in the Selection by Position section detailing the .iloc method.
- With Series, the syntax works exactly as with an ndarray
- With DataFrame, slicing inside of `[]` **slices the rows**.

So it is just a convenient way of ndarray-style row selection with `.iloc[]`, which knows `2:-2` means `2:len(dd)-2:1` (endpoint excluded). Therefore, rows with `index=2,3,4` are selected.

`dd[['o']][2:-2]` also returns the same rows as `dd[2:-2]` because `dd[['o']]` is a dataframe with the same index.